# React child prop rendering before parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am following along with Stephen Grider's Simple Redux Simple Starter on Udemy. Basically, all I need to do is to return the number of videos from the youtube api to the DOM. Right under the input on the picture below should display a 5 when `{props.videos.length}` is called in video_list.js, but always returns 0. Is the child prop rendering first, or is the child's state not being updated properly? Note that first console log is from the video_list, and the second is from the index.js inside the App class.

Index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
const API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { videos: [] };

        YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards'}, (videos) => {
            console.log(videos);
            this.setState = ({ videos }); 
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

video_list.js

```
import React from 'react';

const VideoList = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <ul className='col-md-4 list-group'>
            {props.videos.length}
        </ul>
    }
};

export default VideoList;
```

[image]

Comment: It's an async call. They take time. In general async setup should happen in componentDidMount and you need to handle the rendering before the results are returned.

Comment: You are overwriting the `setState` function. Remove the `=` to call it instead. `this.setState({ videos }); `

Comment: @Tholle that was it! Thank you

Comment: Ah good catch, missed that. Still do what I said though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `setState` function. Remove the `=` to call it instead.

```
YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards'}, (videos) => {
  this.setState({ videos }); 
});
```